# How can I dynamically add columns in my view

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, dynamic-view

Can you suggest to me how to handle this view if column added dynamically its may be 5 to 10 in future?
Please look at my screen shot for response and view.
Leave Type Fixed but other columns may be increased  or short   [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sbqg9.png)   web Response  [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0oZk5.png) Second Activity

[image]
[image]

Please give me idea how to handle like recycler view and tab view pager.

Comment: Hallo Abhishek Maheshwari, at first you should share your idea to achieve that and some code to show what you've tried so far.

Comment: You can add rows and collum dynamically , this link may helpful to you http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/dynamically-add-items-to-listview-in-android/

Comment: @RobinVinzenz I have no idea that's a region I have to send this question what is the best idea and solution for this.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please see [ask] and [mcve].